Can anyone ID this bike? NSW, Australia
My Dad was a mamil (middle aged man in lycra) in the 80's. He was an enthusiast and a collector and since he passed away in 2022, I have been slowly sorting through his many collections.
It feels like time to find new homes for his bikes.
People on this site have been a great and have already helped identify one of his bikes.
Sharing pics of another bike, Dad's blue bike. thanks in anticipation of your thoughts.
















The Shimano M700 "deer head" derailleur was first made in late 1983 so most likely used on a 1984 model bicycle. It ended production in 1987 when the M730 was introduced. If the derailleur is original the bike would have been made between about 1984 and 1986.

The time period sounds right @DavidD

Hi Sarah, what size are these bicycles?

This is another interesting bike. Every aspect of it is "the best" that was available at the time.
It is a very early mountain bike featuring components that were some of the first designed or marketed specifically for mountain bikes. The brake levers are deliberately designed to look and feel like motorcycle levers. This one is almost certainly another custom-made frame.
The tubeset, Triple Butted, a top-tier choice, and the Cinelli-Supercorsa-inspired seatpost clamp add strength to this possibility. I don't think another, better known, mass-market maker would copy the iconic cinelli feature but an artisan framebuilder might.
The rear derailleur is one of the more famous, and you can read about it here:
https://www.disraeligears.co.uk/site/shimano_deore_xt_derailleur_m700_1st_style.html
This bike was top-notch and very high end when it was new. I bet it feels really light even now.
Rebour, etched into the saddle, is a famous illustrator, well known for his drawings of cycle components in cycle catalogues and magazines, before photos were available. Is it signed by the man himself? (it's not- - that's a standard model but still rather el1te)
The style of the handlebars is called "bullmoose" and they, too, were sometimes custom made though could be factory made .

What tells you this is a custom frame? There were several other mass manufactured triple-butted lugged frame mountain bikes in this time period. From a parts perspective, it looks like several other high end mountain bikes - except for the Campagnola hubs and the leather seat. Bullmoose handlebars were on several makes of bike during the '80s, they were easily purchased then and you can still buy them today.

@DavidD interesting question. The sloping fork crown is an unusually fancy casting for a mass market bike. The bottom bracket lug looks like it's ported: an oversized fillet brazed tube to the bottom bracket shell to form the lug for the downtube. However, the brake bridge looks TIG welded or slightly messy, so I'm not necessarily correct in my assertion.

And perhaps not custom...but a small run certainly

thanks @Noise it is a light bike.  I noticed Shimano engraved in the blue painted metal adjacent to the derailleur. I wondered if this meant it was a Shimano bike?
